# Parsing HTML source to make some replacements

Tags: php, parsing, dom, html-parsing, phpquery

I am trying to parse an HTML source to make some changes on it.
Until now I was using Simple HTML Dom Parser but I am facing some memory leaking although using clear() function as in documentation.

So I decided to try PHP DOM and PHPQUERY but both are giving me the exact same problem. Even just loading dom, it is breaking in the exactly same location. It is removing some tags.

php dom

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$html = $dom->saveHTML();
```

phpquery

```
require('phpQuery.php');
$html = phpQuery::newDocumentHTML($html);
```

source code page before

```
<input type="radio" id="logo_show0" name="logo_show" value="1" checked="checked" />

...

$(document).ready(function() {
    var tab = $('<li class=" active"><a href="#general" data-toggle="tab">Plugin</a></li>');
    $('#myTabTabs').append(tab);
});
```

source code page after

```
<input type="radio" id="logo_show0" name="logo_show" value="1" checked />

...

$(document).ready(function() {
    var tab = $('<li class=" active"><a href="#general" data-toggle="tab">Plugin');
    $('#myTabTabs').append(tab);
});
```

Has been removed `checked` and closing tags `</a></li>`.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: did you tell the doctype to DOMDocument ? or try the others options of "loadHTML" http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php. for JavaScript, try to protect the code whith CDATA for example

Comment: @mmm Thanks. Unfortunately I have no control over the code to parse, even so it is possible to protect scripts with CDATA as you suggested? How can I do it?